# javascript array with numeric index without undefineds

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

suppose I do..

```
var arr = Array();
var i = 3333;
arr[i] = "something";
```

if you do a stringify of this array it will return a string with a whole bunch of undefined numeric entries for those entries whose index is less than 3333...

is there a way to make javascript not do this?

I know that I can use an object {} but I would rather not since I want to do array operations such as shift() etc which are not available for objects

Comment: Is there a reason why you need index 3333 rather than 0 as the start? Maybe you should re-think your indexing.

Comment: What would you expect stringify to return?

Comment: You are misusing the array data structure. The best thing here would be to use an object and `call` the relevant Array prototype methods.

Comment: "**is there a way to make javascript not do this?...**" What would you want it to do instead?

Comment: Is it possible to use a filtered version of the array when stringifying? i.e. `JSON.stringify(arr.filter(function(i,v){return typeof v !== "undefined"}))`

Comment: @Asad—there is no need for any test in the function since [`filter`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) is only called for members that exist. Also, members may exist and have a value of `undefined`, your test (if it was necessary at all) would be `function(i,v,arr){return arr.hasOwnProperty(i);}` which will always be true since it's only called for members that exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an array per the OP, it only has one member with a property name of "333" and a length of 334 because length is always set to be at least one greater than the highest index. e.g.

```
var a = new Array(1000);
```

has a length of 1000 and no members,

```
var a = [];
var a[999] = 'foo';
```

has a length of 1000 and one member with a property name of "999".

The speedy way to only get defined members is to use for..in:

```
function myStringifyArray(a) {
  var s = [];
  var re = /^\d+$/;

  for (var p in a) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(p) && re.test(p)) {
      s.push(a[p]);
    }
  }
  return '' + s;
}
```

Note that the members may be returned out of order. If that is an issue, you can use a for loop instead, but it will be slower for very sparse arrays:

```
function myStringifyArray(a) {
  var s = [];
  var re = /^\d+$/;

  for (var i=0, iLen=a.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      s.push(a[i]);
    }
  }
  return '' + s;
}
```

In some older browsers, iterating over the array actually created the missing members, but I don't think that's in issue in modern browsers.

Please test the above thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

The literal representation of an array has to have all the items of the array, otherwise the 3334th item would not end up at index 3333.

You can replace all undefined values in the array with something else that you want to use as empty items:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (typeof arr[i] == 'undefined') arr[i] = '';
}
```

Another alternative would be to build your own stringify method, that would create assignments instead of an array literal. I.e. instead of a format like this:

```
[0,undefined,undefined,undefined,4,undefined,6,7,undefined,9]
```

your method would create something like:

```
(function(){
  var result = [];
  result[0] = 0;
  result[4] = 4;
  result[6] = 6;
  result[7] = 7;
  result[9] = 9;
  return result;
}())
```

However, a format like that is of course not compatible with JSON, if that is what you need.

Comment: The special version could just use elisions, which are valid in an array literal and do not create the "missing" members, the above would be `0,,,,4,,6,7,,9` which (not surprisingly) is what `Array.prototype.toString` returns.

Comment: @RobG: Nice, I didn't know that had wide support for arrays. It's not supported for objects in IE for example.